# Vue.js set prop values to empty if nothing is passed

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

So I have this interface of discounts:

```
export interface Discount {
    id: number
    name: string
    type: string
}
```

And I use it on my prop in Vue.js app like this:

```
export default class DiscountsEdit extends Vue {
    @Prop({ default: () => {} }) discount!: Discount;
}
```

I use twig template engine and I pass empty discount array into the Vue component. I would like to have the whole discount object with empty variable values like:

```
id: 0
name: ''
type: ''
```

Is it possible to set automatically on Vue.js side, or I have to define those values as empty before sending it to Vue side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value of your object prop could be like :

```
 @Prop({ default: () => ({id:0,name:'',type:''}) }) discount!: Discount;
```